# QTCP connection as QThread

Tags: qt4, qthread, qtcpsocket

so here's the thing..

I'm making an embedded program using linux touchscreen device.

My program has to make a connection to the server thru tcp. The problem is that my device boots directly in my program and if the server isnt listening, all functionality is lost because of the used connection struct i use:

```
    while(!socket->waitForConnected(-1)){

         socket->connectToHost(serverIP, port);

         thread->sleep(1);
    }
```

(the server wont be always listening, so that's the "major" problem)

The solution i've found is to make this connection as a thread, but i couldn't do the code. Can anyone help? is this the only solution? if so, does anyone knows good documents that make this kind of things?

Really appreciate the help, TY!

By the way, i'm using Qt 4.7!

Comment: What class does socket belong to?

Comment: to QTcpSocket.., serverIP type is QHostAddress and port is quint16

Comment: Why do not you use signals and slots?

Comment: i also did that "thread->sleep(1)" just so the program doesn't bug while trying to connect nonstop

Comment: I do not see the need to use threads.

Comment: signal could be "hostFound()"?

Comment: Use a QTimer, and on each call you try to connect if it is not connected

Comment: Ok, gonna try it right now, really appreciate bro!!

Comment: When socket is connected, then delete the timer and delete it.

Comment: ok, i did your solution and worked as a charm!! really appreciate, mate!

Answer (score 0):

just so people can see the solution, i created a slot to make connection:

```
void TCP::iniSetup()
{
    qDebug("Connecting..");
    socket->connectToHost(serverIP, port);

    if(socket->state() == QTcpSocket::ConnectedState){
         timer->stop();
    qDebug("Connected!");
    }
}
```

and connected the timeout (from QTimer object) to this slot. To remake the connection (if the connection is lost), i used another slot just to restart the timer. no need to remake the signals and slots connections!!

All credits and appreciation to @eyllanesc, thanks bro!